# Remove slide number upp letf corner of slideshow in Nivo Slider

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

Can anyone tell me how to remove the numbers "12345" in the upper right hand corner of this Nivo Slider slide show:

http://www.sabatinossliceofnewyork.com/nivo.php

Answer (score 3):

Add the following css rule:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following option when initialising the slider:

```
$('element').nivoSlider({
    ...
    controlNav  : false,
    ...
});
```